# Why redirecting FINDSTR output produce UNIX line ending?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix

When I issue this command:
`FINDSTR /I /N "<sdk:extra>" addon.xml` output is:

```
973:    <sdk:extra>
995:    <sdk:extra>
1017:    <sdk:extra>
1036:    <sdk:extra>
1057:    <sdk:extra>
1078:    <sdk:extra>
1098:    <sdk:extra>
1118:    <sdk:extra>
1140:    <sdk:extra>
1161:    <sdk:extra>
1182:    <sdk:extra>
1203:    <sdk:extra>
1223:    <sdk:extra>
1244:    <sdk:extra>
```

But when I redirect it to file with this command:

`FINDSTR /I /N "<sdk:extra>" addon.xml > find_s.txt`

`find_s.txt` have UNIX line ending (Newline or EOL if you like it more).

Anybody know why? I need a DOS line ending, or it breaks the whole batch.

How do you convert file from UNIX to DOS line endings in Windows batch?

(without using external binary or powershell) (.js and .vbs are fine)

Comment: The findstr function is probably not relevant. Likely it's just that the file is in unix format to begin with. See ansgar's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-eol-to-windows-eol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTT is right that your file should be in unix format.  If you don't mind the order, you can pipe the output to sort first.  Otherwise need another utility.

```
FINDSTR /I /N "<sdk:extra>" addon.xml | sort > find_s.txt
```

Comment: This look like perfect solution, no need to another commands or temp files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a bat file, you can

```
del find_s_dos.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (find_s.txt) do @echo %%i>>find_s_dos.txt
```